# Error 'Objective-C method ':' provided by method ' ' does not match the requirement's selector when I try to rename using @objc(newName)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a method

```
public func presentSomeView(with viewId: String? = nil, from viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((UIViewController) -> ())? = nil)
```

I am trying to have the Objective-C API be

```
presentSomeViewWithId: from: completion:
```

Instead, the default is:

```
presentSomeViewWith: from: completion:
```

To try to fix this, I have written:

```
@objc(presentSomeViewWithId:from:completion:) 
public func presentSomeView(with viewId: String? = nil, from viewController: UIViewController, completion: ((UIViewController) -> ())? = nil)
```

Xcode presents the following ***"Fix-It"*** error:

```
Objective-C method 'presentSomeViewWithId:from:completion:' provided by method 'presentSomeView(with:from:completion:)' does not match the requirement's selector ('presentSomeViewWith:from:completion:')

Replace 'presentSomeViewWithId:from:completion:' with 'presentSomeViewWith:from:completion:'
```

What am I missing here?  I've searched everywhere and by all suggestions, this ***should*** work.

Comment: What if you say `WithID` instead (note the caps)?

Comment: Do you see the error on the declaration or when you try to call the function from an Objective-C file?  I pasted the declaration into a Swift file and did not get an error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Xcode 10.1/Swift 4.2.

Comment: The error message makes me wonder if this method is part of a protocol implementation. Is that the case? If so, and if the protocol is `@objc`, the method selectors are going to be constrained by the protocol, and you won't be able to change them.

Comment: Turns out the methods WERE part of a protocol and that I needed to rename them there. Problem solved

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Resubmit your suggestion as an Answer, I'll upvote it — and/also then it should be marked as the Accepted Answer; this deserves more visibility, and you, credit. :)